# Why is my program not reading the first integer in the text file?

Tags: java, text-files

I have completed the metho to the point of it locating the txt file with the grades, read them put and then put them into an array and then output the specified values we need. For some reason, it is not taking all the integers.  for example, if I put in:

6, 87, 23, 90

it will only read the last three.

87, 23, and 90

```
//reads the data from the file
private static int[] readExamScores(String  userFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File inputFile = new File(userFile);
    Scanner stats = new Scanner(inputFile);

    try{
        int scores[] = new int[stats.nextInt()];
        int i = 0;
        while (stats.hasNext()){
            scores[i] = stats.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "There are " + (i) + " scores. \n");
        Arrays.sort(scores);
        return scores;
    }
    finally {
        stats.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `int scores[] = new int[stats.nextInt()];` IS reading the first `int`, and using it to allocate an array of that many elements

Comment: it's programed to use the first number as being size (or count if you prefer) - but how you don't know what you have coded?

Answer (score 2):

Because your index is already moved by 1 due to init and increment at same time
eg stats.nextInt()

I propose fix with arraylist as scanner 'consume' what it returns if you count tokens in a string line or read it .

```
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>()
       int i = 0;
        while (stats.hasNext()){
            scores.add(stats.nextInt());
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: sorry I reread , best is to count number of token to init scores array